# Code works in IE8 but not in IE10

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code on my web page:

```
Protected Function SendData(ByVal filepath As String) As Boolean

        Dim ReturnResults As Boolean = False
        Dim iStream As System.IO.Stream = Nothing

        Dim buffer As Byte() = New [Byte](9999) {}
        Dim length As Integer
        Dim dataToRead As Long
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath)
        Try
            iStream = New System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)
            dataToRead = iStream.Length
            Response.Clear()
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename)
            While dataToRead > 0
                If Response.IsClientConnected Then
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000)
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                    Response.Flush()
                    buffer = New [Byte](9999) {}
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length
                Else
                    dataToRead = -1
                End If
            End While
            Response.Close()
            ReturnResults = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If iStream IsNot Nothing Then
                iStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return ReturnResults
    End Function
```

This above code works well in IE8, it lets us open and save the file in IE8, but when I try the same code in IE10 the it gives me an error saying "File cannot be opened". I am not sure if it is IE problem or something else, but I am not sure how to change the above code so that it starts working in IE10.

I also put the tag above the web page that says

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>'
```

I also tried doing compability mode. I also put the above in web.config file so that it applies to the whole application, but nothing seems to be working. I also tried

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>'
```

that doesn't work either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to open?  Where do you see this error message?

Comment: What happens if you replace the `ContentDisposition` line with `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & filename & """")`?

Comment: I am trying to open text files.

Comment: I can write the code differently too if this code does not seem right